# Sed/Awk/Cut GNU transform text lines to single line

Tags: regex, awk, sed, gnu, gawk

I have the following type of data:

```
3869|Jennifer Smith
10413 NE 71st Street
Vancouver, WA
98662
360-944-9578
jsmith@yahoo.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
--
3875|Joan L Doe
422 1/2 14th Ave E
Seattle, WA
98112
206-322-7666
jldoe@comcast.net|1234-1234-1234-1234|03-2013|123
--
3862|Dana Doe
24235 NE 7th Pl
Sammamish, WA
98074
425 868-2227
jsmith@hotmail.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
--
3890|John Smith
10470 SW 67th Ave
Tigard, OR
97223
5032205213
john.smith@gmail.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
```

I need to transform it to:

```
3869|Jennifer Smith|10413 NE 71st Street|Vancouver, WA|98662|360-944-9578|jsmith@yahoo.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
3875|Joan L Doe|422 1/2 14th Ave E|Seattle, WA|98112|206-322-7666|jldoe@comcast.net|1234-1234-1234-1234|03-2013|123
3862|Dana Doe|24235 NE 7th Pl|Sammamish, WA|98074|425 868-2227|jsmith@hotmail.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
3890|John Smith|10470 SW 67th Ave|Tigard, OR|97223|5032205213|john.smith@gmail.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
```

or better:

```
3869|Jennifer Smith|10413 NE 71st Street|Vancouver|WA|98662|360-944-9578|jsmith@yahoo.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
3875|Joan L Doe|422 1/2 14th Ave E|Seattle|WA|98112|206-322-7666|jldoe@comcast.net|1234-1234-1234-1234|03-2013|123
3862|Dana Doe|24235 NE 7th Pl|Sammamish|WA|98074|425 868-2227|jsmith@hotmail.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
3890|John Smith|10470 SW 67th Ave|Tigard|OR|97223|5032205213|john.smith@gmail.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
```

any idea how to automate this using GNU sed, awk, cu or perl/python whatever...
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is very nice, but it *nearly* works (missing last line):

```
$ awk '{if (/^--/) {print a; a=""} else { a=a"|"$0}}' file
|3869|Jennifer Smith|10413 NE 71st Street|Vancouver, WA|98662|360-944-9578|jsmith@yahoo.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
|3875|Joan L Doe|422 1/2 14th Ave E|Seattle, WA|98112|206-322-7666|jldoe@comcast.net|1234-1234-1234-1234|03-2013|123
|3862|Dana Doe|24235 NE 7th Pl|Sammamish, WA|98074|425 868-2227|jsmith@hotmail.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
```

#### Update

If you add an extra

```
--
```

at the end of your file, it *completly* works:

```
$ awk '{if (/^--/) {print a; a=""} else { a=a"|"$0}}' file
|3869|Jennifer Smith|10413 NE 71st Street|Vancouver, WA|98662|360-944-9578|jsmith@yahoo.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
|3875|Joan L Doe|422 1/2 14th Ave E|Seattle, WA|98112|206-322-7666|jldoe@comcast.net|1234-1234-1234-1234|03-2013|123
|3862|Dana Doe|24235 NE 7th Pl|Sammamish, WA|98074|425 868-2227|jsmith@hotmail.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
|3890|John Smith|10470 SW 67th Ave|Tigard, OR|97223|5032205213|john.smith@gmail.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
```

This happens because my code waits for an `--` to print what is buffering.

Comment: Works completely well either way. I got the idea.

Answer (score 6):

Using `sed`

```
sed -n ':a;$!N;/--/!s/\n/|/g;ta;P' inputFile


$ sed -n ':a;$!N;/--/!s/\n/|/g;ta;P' temp 
3869|Jennifer Smith|10413 NE 71st Street|Vancouver, WA|98662|360-944-9578|jsmith@yahoo.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
3875|Joan L Doe|422 1/2 14th Ave E|Seattle, WA|98112|206-322-7666|jldoe@comcast.net|1234-1234-1234-1234|03-2013|123
3862|Dana Doe|24235 NE 7th Pl|Sammamish, WA|98074|425 868-2227|jsmith@hotmail.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
3890|John Smith|10470 SW 67th Ave|Tigard, OR|97223|5032205213|john.smith@gmail.com|1234567890123456|03-2013|123
```

#### Explaination:

- `:a` Create a label a.
- `$!` If not the last line; do
- `N` get a new line
- `/--/!` if line does not match this regex; do
- `/s/\n/|/g` substitute new line with pipe
- `ta` branch back to label if the substitution was successful
- `P` print the line.

**Note:** Here is the difference between `p`, `P`, `n` and `N`.

- The `n` command will print out the current pattern space and read in
  the next line of input.
- The `N` command does not print out the
  current pattern space. It reads in the next line, but appends a new
  line character along with the input line itself to the pattern space.
- The `p` command prints the entire pattern space.
- The `P` command
  only prints the first part of the pattern space, up to the NEWLINE
  character.

Comment: Nice way! Could you explain the flags you are using? sed is always very cryptic.

Comment: Thanks ... added the explanation and modified to remove extra pipe.

Comment: Impressing, this explanation is very professional. It goes straight to my bookmarks. +1 again if I could.

Comment: You can't tell (since I am a dark skinned man) but I am blushing. :)

Answer (score 4):

A slightly more idiomatic awk solution:

```
awk -F'\n' -vRS='\n--\n' -vOFS='|' '{$1=$1;print}' test.in
```

Tell it incoming records are separated by a line consisting of `--` and fields are separated by newlines, and outgoing fields should be separated by `|` and records should be separated by the standard newline. `$1 = $1` forces a reformatting conforming to this.

If the file doesn't end with a `--`, you will get an extra `|` on the end, if you need to avoid this you can change this slightly:

```
awk -F'\n' -vRS='\n--\n' -vOFS='|' '{if($NF==""){NF--}$1=$1;print}' test.in
```

Comment: or `awk '{$NF==""?NF--:$1=$1}1' FS='\n' OFS='|' RS='\n--\n' test.in`